# Github - How to Merge PR with Fast-Forwarded Rebase Without CLI

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Problem: it's not possible to do a fast-forward rebase merge using the GitHub UI. The PR option "Rebase and Merge" rewrites the commit time and author for the rebased commits.

From the GitHub Documentation, it says "A workaround for this is to rebase and merge locally, and then push the changes to the pull request's base branch." [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#rebasing-and-merging-your-commits). So, this is possible but must be done with git CLI. Knowing this, I'd like to make a GitHub Action that can make doing this more convenient. Not letting devs press the merge button for PRs sucks, and having to do it via CLI also sucks.

Idea: Change the behavior of the "Rebase and Merge" merge option with an action. If I can get an action to trigger when I click "Rebase and Merge", maybe I can change the commit to be fast-forwarded instead.

Is something possible to solve this problem, and is there any way to implemented the proposed solution? I've considered triggering an action on `pull_request.closed` status but I believe that would trigger after the commit, requiring some rewriting shenanigans if I went that route and was correct about the order of operations. Just trying to brainstorm my options, if any.

There is an action on the marketplace that triggers on PR *comment* [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fast-forward-pr) as an example of what I'm trying to do, but I want to be able to click the merge button. If I enforce writing a comment instead of merging, that will surely create friction and mistakes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you care if GH always forces the rebase, even if it sometimes doesn't need to? (Other than the rewritten committer author and time.)

Comment: @TTT this results in different commit hashes, so in many cases the commits aren't considered equal. This can be seen in the GitHub UI where the branch merged from will have the "x commits ahead, x commits behind" message after a rebase. fast-forward (or not using force too, I think) would make this not occur AFIAK

Comment: @TTT another way to look at it is, I want the base and head branches to point to the same commit after a rebase, right now they don't. They point to two different commits that alter the repo in the same way.

Comment: @TTT Lastly, the way GitHub creates the new commits can't be signed by their internal GPG key, so the rebased commits can be verified in the feature branch but will become unverified in the target branch. "When using the Rebase and Merge option on a pull request, it's important to note that the commits in the head branch are added to the base branch without commit signature verification. ... GitHub creates a modified commit ... this means that GitHub didn't truly create this commit, and can't therefore sign it as a generic system user."

Comment: Right, those are all things that happen with a rebase. What GH does differently is it always does the rebase, even if it isn't needed. Let's assume GH did it the normal way (skip the rebase and ff if possible). I'm curious why you are OK with sometimes having the commits rewritten, and sometimes not? It sounds to me like you never want the rebase, and instead just want the fast-forward part of the merge.

Comment: If my last comment it true and you actually do only want ff, then this could explain why GH forces the rebase- so that you don't try to use this merge strategy for FF only and occasionally regret it when someone else completes a PR seconds before you do.

Comment: @TTT I guess you're right, thinking of my use-case the rebase isn't ever required, I just want the fast-forward to have two branches commit graphs to be the same. Can you explain why I'd regret FF only if someone else merged before me? I'm assuming the FF merge would just fail, and I'd be expected to rebase and try again

Comment: You wouldn't regret FF-only if that option existed. But you would regret this strategy of "rebase, merge" if it *sometimes* did a fast forward without the rebase. This is my guess as to why GH implemented this way, so that in your situation you don't ever use rebase, merge. Basically, it sounds like you shouldn't use this strategy. I'd recommend using regular merge for the PR in your situation, or else push the branch outside of the PR if you need fast-forward.

Comment: Side Note- I doubt you can "change the behavior" of the merge button. But even if you could, I think in your case it would be safer to change the behavior of the Regular merge strategy to FF if possible, rather than the rebase, merge strategy. At least with regular merge you don't change any commits, you would either get a merge commit or not. (Presumably an accidental extra merge commit is no big deal compared to accidentally rewriting the branch.)